# What is $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

How to solve the following limit question?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^{n^2}$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try finding the limit of the logarithm of the expression.

Answer (score 6):

Pass to the logarithm inside the exponential:
$$e^{-n}(1+1/n)^{n^2}=\exp(-n+n^2\ln(1+1/n))$$
Since $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+o(x^2)$ at $0$, you get $-n+n^2\ln(1+1/n)=-1/2+o(1)$ so the sequence $e^{-n}(1+1/n)^{n^2}$ converges and its limit is $e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to use the fact that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$ 
So it will be 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^n}\bigg(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\bigg)^n $$

Comment: I hope you're not suggesting the same as dato. You're facing a $1^\infty$ indeterminate form.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Thanks, i know that, but how it helps to get the answer?

Comment: @Sava: Note that, $ \frac{1}{e^n}\bigg(\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\bigg)^n= \bigg(\frac{1}{e}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\bigg)^n .$

Comment: @ Mhenni Benghorbal Thank you, but the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, and I don't see how to get it using your remark

Comment: @PeterTamaroff $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{e}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\bigg)^n $$
$$\frac{1}{e}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n \sim \frac{1}{e} \bigg[e-\frac{e}{2 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right) \bigg] \sim 1-\frac{1}{2n}$$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty}u^v=e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}(u-1)v}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ Will this help?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\displaystyle &&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}\frac{1}{e^n}\\
 &=&\displaystyle e^{n^2ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-n}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(n^2ln(1+\frac{1}{n})-n\right)}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow0^+}\left(\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^2ln(1+m)-\frac{1}{m}\right)}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow0^+}\left(\frac{ln(1+m)-m}{m^2}\right)}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{1+m}-1}{2m}}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-m}{2m(1+m)}}\\
 &=&e^{\displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow0^+}\frac{-1}{2(1+m)}}\\
&=&e^{-\frac{1}{2}} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: why are you answering 5 year old answered questions?

Comment: @orange There's nothing wrong in answering old questions

Comment: When they already have answers?

Comment: I am reading this another two years later and finding it useful.