# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)^{n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{e^n}$

Tags: limits

> Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigr)^{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{e^n}$

We have:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigr)^{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{e^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^{n^2\ln\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)}}{e^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n^2\ln\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigr)-n}
$$

Then I have no idea. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360510/what-is-lim-n-to-infty-frac1en-bigl1-frac1n-bigrn2?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of reducing everything to a single exponential is good. Now you have to evaluate
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(n^2\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)-n\Bigr)
$$
You can try computing instead (with $1/x=t$ after the equality)
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(x^2\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)-x\Bigr)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln(1+t)-t}{t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t-t^2/2+o(t^2)-t}{t^2}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Instead of a Taylor expansion you can use l'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln(1+t)-t}{t^2}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{1}{1+t}-1}{2t}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-n = \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{n(n-x)}{x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-z}{1+\frac{z}{n}}\,dz$$
hence by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-n\right]=\int_{0}^{1}-z\,dz = \color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$